# Why I can't inflate a layout where the layout contains a fragment?

Tags: java, android

I want to have a PopupWindow with a layout that contains a fragment but I can't inflate the layout
My code is:

```
      View viewInsertPoints = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.insert_points, null);
      PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(viewInsertPonts,null);
```

where insert_points.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/row"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/footer_table_row_4_jucatori_in_echipa_popup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_of_16"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="@dimen/spazio_tra_celle">

    <com.ionvaranita.belotenote.borders.BorderedEditText
        android:id="@+id/puncte_noi_edit_text_popup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000080"
        android:textSize="@dimen/footer_text_size"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <com.ionvaranita.belotenote.borders.BorderedEditText
        android:id="@+id/puncte_joaca_edit_text_popup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"

        android:gravity="right"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="@dimen/footer_text_size" />

    <com.ionvaranita.belotenote.borders.BorderedEditText
        android:id="@+id/puncte_voi_edit_text_popup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#006400"
        android:textSize="@dimen/footer_text_size"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/calculator_popup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/note"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <com.ionvaranita.belotenote.KeyboardFragment
        android:id="@+id/container_keyboard_4_jucatori_in_echipa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding_of_16"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_of_16"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</TableRow>


</LinearLayout>
```

where the KeyboardFragment is a fragment that contains a personalised simple keyboard. The keys of the keyboard are buttons with values, when I click the button it will write the value on the selected BorderedEditText object of the insert_points.xml layout

**and the error:**

```
19 09:11:36.045 13393-13393/com.ionvaranita.belotenote E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.ionvaranita.belotenote, PID: 13393
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ionvaranita.belotenote/com.ionvaranita.belotenote.Tabella4JucatoriInEchipa}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #79: Binary XML file line #79: Class is not a View com.ionvaranita.belotenote.KeyboardFragment
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
                                                                         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #79: Binary XML file line #79: Class is not a View com.ionvaranita.belotenote.KeyboardFragment
                                                                         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #79: Class is not a View com.ionvaranita.belotenote.KeyboardFragment
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.ionvaranita.belotenote.KeyboardFragment cannot be cast to android.view.View
                                                                            at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:2469)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                            at com.ionvaranita.belotenote.Tabella4JucatoriInEchipa.onCreate(Tabella4JucatoriInEchipa.java:92)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

**Can you tell me please an alternative of my intent?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the issue:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.ionvaranita.belotenote.KeyboardFragment cannot be cast to android.view.View
```

You need to declare your `Fragment` as such in the layout file, try this:

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <fragment 
        android:name="com.ionvaranita.belotenote.KeyboardFragment"
        android:id="@+id/container_keyboard_4_jucatori_in_echipa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding_of_16"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_of_16"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</TableRow>
```

If you leave out the `fragment` bit in the xml, Android will expect the class of `KeyboardFragment` to extend `View`...

Comment: it works with name atribute, thanks for suggestion 
<fragment           android:name="com.ionvaranita.belotenote.KeyboardFragment"
            android:id="@+id/container_keyboard_4_jucatori_in_echipa"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding_of_16"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_of_16"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

Comment: I upvoted your question, please accept the answer when you get a second ;)